# Riemann surface of the hypergeometric function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, hypergeometric-function, branch-cuts, branch-points

The hypergeometric function $_2F_1(a,b,c,z)$ has a branch cut extending from $z=1$ to $z=\infty$. Does this define an infinite-sheeted Riemann surface (like that for $\log{z}$) or one with a finite number of sheets (like that for $\sqrt{z}$)?

Comment: Depends on the type of singularity.  That depends on the parameters $a,b,c$.  If $a$ is a negative integer, then it is a polynomial, so it is single-valued.  If $c-a-b$ is not an integer, then near $z=1$ the Riemann surface can have a singularity like $(1-z)^{c-a-b}$ so finitely many leaves (if $c-a-b$ is rational) or infinitely many leaves (if irrational).  When $c-a-b$ is an integer it can have a logarithmic singularity at $z=1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that answers my question! So the answer is based on the behavior of the function near $z=1$ or $z=\infty$, and can be different near both? How do I understand this difference?